# copyq custom command if then statement problem

Tags: copyq

I've tried the copyq example code:

```
copyq:
if (str(data(mimeClipboardMode)) == 'selection')
    popup('selection changed')
else
    popup('clipboard changed')
```

it works as intended, i.e. if the mouse selects something the 'if' part executes, if I copy something with copy+c then the 'else' part is executed, however the following modified code executes the 'else' statement regardless if it's a mouse selection or copy+c

```
copyq:
    if (str(data(mimeClipboardMode)) == 'selection')
;
else
    var window = str(data('application/x-copyq-owner-window-title'))
    popup(window)
```

I can't find an answer or a hint anywhere. What am I missing?